# Count days between two dates and activate mandatory input if result is “less than 4”?

Tags: vba, excel-2019

I want to do VBA code as below.

1. Cell J2 is set to today()
2. Cell J4 can be set another date by user
3. Cell L4 set a formula =NETWORKDAY(J2-J4)-1, to calculate the exact days between the dates in J2 & J4
4. if the outcome in L4 is <4, user could continue to fill in the form;
5. Otherwise, 2 msg box pop up in sequence

   - msgbox : 'Application takes at least 4-7 workings days';
   - msgbox : 'Please pick another date'
6. return to Cell J4 which will be cleared as well
7. User should input the date in J4 again

Here is my code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Range("L4") >= 4 Then Exit Sub

Else

msg = MsgBox("Application takes at least 4-7 working days", vbOKOnly, "Reminder")

Range("J4").Select

Selection.ClearContents

msg = MsgBox("Please choose another date", vbOKOnly)

End If

End sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check to see if the `Worksheet_Change` `Target` is the date cell that the user is updating (J4). If it is, check `L4` and pop your message box. Lastly turn events back on so it can trigger again next time there is a change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Range("J4"), Target) Is Nothing Then:
        If Range("L4").Value < 4 Then
             msg = MsgBox("Application takes at least 4-7 working days", vbOKOnly, "Reminder")
             Range("J4").ClearContents
             meg = MsgBox("Please choose another date", vbOKOnly)
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.  However, it doesn't work. No pop window at all. No event activated.
Might the problem be that NETWORKDAYS formula set in L4? I dun know.....ToT

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner. I suspect that question was right-on. I've updated the logic to check the correct cell.

Comment: Thousands thanks for your assistance.  It works !! I'm much appreciated for your help!! U've solved a big big problem for me !

Answer (score 0):

Before End Sub you have to re-enable events like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Range("L4") >= 4 Then
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
Else
    msg = MsgBox("Application takes at least 4-7 working days", vbOKOnly, "Reminder")
    Range("J4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    msg = MsgBox("Please choose another date", vbOKOnly)
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End sub
```

or another implementation if only disable events if date is not good.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)



If Range("L4") >= 4 Then
Exit Sub
Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    msg = MsgBox("Application takes at least 4-7 working days", vbOKOnly, "Reminder")
    Range("J4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    msg = MsgBox("Please choose another date", vbOKOnly)
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End sub
```

Sidenote: Gives more information about the error parameter (what is displayed, which line, relevant values etc.) this result more precise and faster answers mainly if more complex codes.

Comment: I've already added, but it still doesn't work....

Comment: @joffee Edited. If you leave when >4 there also need enable events.